# Why RLS only works on tabular not within Power bi?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, user-roles, ssas-tabular

I have a tabular cube (built in VS) where I have RLS, it works fine. I use the cube, for 2 reports... One is for everyone where I just show personal data and the other one is for Leadership.

(I do the trick by having an 'access table' where I set it to 1 , so the filter is enabled in the 'personal report')

The same exact set up doesnt seem to work , when i build the cube/model directly in power bi. I get this error:
[image]

How is it possible that the exact same set up, doesnt work in Power BI but it does work if I use an external cube .

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible that the exact same set up, doesn't work in Power BI but it does work if I use an external cube .

This is likely caused by a change in that the SSAS server doesn't have.  SSAS 2022 will probably behave the same way.

See [Multiple Roles and Limited Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls#issue-multiple-roles-and-limited-relationships), and a relevant community discussion here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/December-Update-Issue-Multiple-Roles-in-Row-Level-Security/idi-p/2282329